# How to detect Java app lock up in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, deadlock, detect

My Java app sometimes lock up, won't even respond to window close mouse click, why ? I'm using Netbean as IDE, I had to use "Cancel Running Task" to exit the locked app, is there a way for it to detect why and fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually means that something is hogging the UI thread. To figure out what, use the debugger to suspend all threads when your app hangs. Then find the UI thread and see where it is at.